# Is there a way to 'lock' an image's history stack in darktable?

Tags: darktable

Does anyone know if there a way to prevent accidental modification of images in darkroom view once happy with the image?

I was working through an image's history stack the other day to see what I done and absent-mindedly applied a new module half-way through the stack - effectively erasing everything I had done. It would be excellent if there was a method to lock the image and prevent future edits without unlocking.

I cannot find anything in the Darktable manual which doesn't bode well for my question.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I'm planning on automating regular and frequent backups of the sidecar files with rdiff-backup partly due to the ease of losing edits.

Answer (score 4):

The lack of an Undo function is one of the worst "features" of darktable... What I normally do is to duplicate the image in lighttable when I am happy with it.

Duplicating in DT simply add another `.xmp` file; if grouping is active you just see one (the most recent) for editing, and the other copy will be unaffected and safe and visible only if  you  ungroup the images.

You can browse the manual around http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch02s02s06.html.php

Comment: Good idea... Had never thought about how grouping would work in this use case, which is convenient.

Comment: Cool, that's a useful work around but I am guessing the consensus is no to the 'lock' function :-) Pity. I like idiot-proofing things against myself.